# Activate venv in vs code

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I have been trying to activate a virtual environment using Python built-in module venv from VSCode, But it didn't work properly And I didn't receive any error message. However, and also If I use `venv\Scripts\activate.bat` command in terminal it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Are you correctly setting up the venv?

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Then in the below section of your vscode taskbar you will find

[image: Important]

Then select your interpreter(env) to use:

[image: Activate]

Answer (score 2):

There are three things that I would check:

1. Does your vs-code have a default virtual environment defined as a user setting?  Is that the one your current workspace is using?
2. Have you moved the folder you are working in since creating a virtual environment?  If so, you should edit your `venv/bin/activate` script so that it has the correct value for the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable.
3. In your project, do you have a `.vscode/settings.json` file that is referring to the wrong location or a location which doesn't exist?  Specifically thinking of the `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"` setting.

These are things that I came across today when I had a similar problem.  Hopefully that helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

{Ctrl+shift+'}

this will open a new terminal and automatically activate your virtual environment, found this in vs code documentation for flask virtual environments.

I also tried venv\Scripts\activate.bat and it wasn't having it; however cant remember the issue I was having.

Hope this saves some one a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Open the interpreter selection widget - either press the `Python 3.x` text button on the bottom right corner of the window or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and start typing "Python Interpreter" until the option to select the widget shows up.
- Click the "Add new environment" option.
- Navigate to `/[your_venv_folder_for_the_directory]/bin/python3` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This should solve the issue.